# JPA Returns null when query.getSingleResult() is returned directly

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

I have a very strange issue with hibernate and jpa. Below are two blocks of code:

```
public Object getObject(Date date) {
    try {

        Query query = entityManager
                .createQuery(
                        "select ob from Object ob where date= :date");
        query.setParameter("date", date);

        return (Object)query.getSingleResult();

    } catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException e) {
        logger.debug(String.format("No Result found - date[%s]",date));
        return null;
    }
}
```

...

```
public Object getObject(Date date) {
    try {

        Query query = entityManager
                .createQuery(
                        "select ob from Object ob where date= :date");
        query.setParameter("date", date);

        Object ret = (Object)query.getSingleResult();
        return ret;


    } catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException e) {
        logger.debug(String.format("No Result found - date[%s]",date));
        return null;
    }
}
```

The first generates an EmptyResultDataAccessException every time even given a valid record where the date matches. The second returns a result as expected. Has anyone encountered this? What causes this behavior?

Please assume all other syntatical things are present(a transaction, initialized entitymanager, etc) the only thing that I change is whether the query results are retrieved directly in the return or assigned to a variable first.

Comment: May be my question could be unhelpful but, are you really sure that the two requests are the same ? Please, perform a simple copy/paste and then retest, I'm pretty sure that your statements are correct.

Comment: I am sitting here with several colleagues, we keep editing and redeploying the jar with only that one change. Its truly bizarre. I continually got a null return from this method. I tried everything under the sun, it wasn't until I moved that `getSingleResult()` call out to an assignment that it began working unexpectedly.

Comment: how does the exception look like exactly? (stacktrace)

Comment: No I am back to square one. I did exactly as I advised you and built an independent example, now that one is back to working. Now I'm not sure this related. I am working dilgigently to attempt to reproduce. The only differences I can't really reproduce is that we are using Compile time aspect weaving to pick up the @Transactional attribute in the deployed app and it is running in a container

Comment: There is some orthogonal cause to this. Its not related to that return statement. Its seems entirely intermittent. I think I'm just changing things at fortuitous times.

Answer (score 1):

It **IS** possible, I encountered it before as well. I think it has something to do with byte code manipulations that Hibernate is doing. To get to the root of it, you have to go to a very deep and dark level of implementation.

When working with Hibernate/JPA I always use the second pattern. It's unfortunate because it makes the code a bit more verbose, but it's not worth plunging into a depth of generated byte code and trying to comprehend it.

Comment: whatever hibernate does, stays in the Query object and possibly the entity. I bet the compiler produces the same output for both versions

Comment: There is lots of byte code manipulation going on in **run-time** in Hibernate to support lazy loading and other concepts. Once the code is manipulated on such a level, it's almost impossible to apply static reasoning about code behavior.

Comment: What hibernate does is code-genereation of entity subclasses, but that has nothing to do with a call to the `Query` object.

Comment: @Bozho there is a simple way to find out man. Maybe I'm crazy. whip up a little example and see if it happens to you hibernate-jpa-2.0 - 1.0.0 final

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible. The two variants are equivalent. There's something you are missing perhaps.

Note that `getSingleResult()` can throw an exception if there is more than 1 result.

Comment: I would be inclined to agree with you. I am totally open to suggestions.

Comment: My guess is you are not running the code you think you are (did not compile/deploy it correctly/have it twice on the classpath), or you are not accessing the data you think you are (each is accessing different database or in different transaction)